# Identifying independent clauses

Tags: conjunctions, clauses, commas

I know that a comma in front of the conjunction 'and' is usally set when *and* is connecting two independent clauses.

I can't decide, though, if the second part of the following sentence is, in fact, an independent clause:

> Boredom comes, and **unsolicited thoughts**

I know that verb-only predicates exist, but does the adjective here count as a predicate so that I end up with two independent clauses?

edit: note that I would very much like to set the comma. I'm not looking for ways to spare me the comma.

Comment: "Boredom comes, and with it, unsolicited thoughts."

Comment: @MarkHubbard so far so good but it alters the sense of the sentence, if only ever so slightly.

Answer (score 1):

It is elliptical.

> Boredom comes and  unsolicited thoughts [come].

The second clause is rather a kind of afterthought.

> Bad things happen, and good things.

With the parallelism of the clauses the main verb of clause #1 is understood to be present in clause #2, even if the grammatical number of the subject is not the same:

> Bad things happen, and a good thing <sup>happens</sup> too, now and then.

The entire verb phrase is understood in clause #2.

> Three men went into a movie theater, and one dog.

Can't this be done in German too?

*Drei Maenner sind ins Kino gegangen, und ein Hund.*